# "cmake --build . [ -- -j<N> ]". What is this command and how do I get it to work? Installing ROOT

Tags: cmake, root

I am trying to install ROOT v6.20.04 using CMake 3.17.0. This is my first time using CMake and I am also not familiar with installing software on macOS, so I am a bit lost. I am following the instructions from the INSTALL script. I've gotten to this point:

```
cmake --build . [ -- -j<N> ]
```

and I have no idea what it means. I naively just tried copying and pasting this into my terminal, though of course it gives back

```
N: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure what directory N should be in this case. Well, for any sort of path I put in for N (I'm in my build directory, so I tried the path to this) I always get the same error:

```
Unknown argument [
Usage: cmake --build <dir> [options] [-- [native-options]]
```

Followed by a bunch of options. On top of "N", I am not sure what the "-j" option does and how to get it to work (the bracketing is also confusing and throwing an error. I'm not sure how to resolve this). I am looking at a list of CMake options and -j is not one of them.

If I understood what this command was meant to be doing, I'd probably be able to figure this out, though I have no idea. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore the `[ -- -j<N> ]`.  Just do  `cmake --build .`.

The `[` `]` are typically used to depict that something is optional. Like the line `cmake` showed you:

```
cmake --build <dir> [options] [-- [native-options]]
```

The `options` part is optional, you can run `cmake` with an option there: `cmake --build /dir --some-option`, or you can just run `cmake --build /dir`. Thus the `options` are presented in `[` `]`. Mandatory arguments are presented inside `<` `>` - you have to pass the directory to `--build` command. It's like a common widely-used not-standard convention that many utilities when showing help or usage screens or in manuals.

As to `cmake`: First with `cmake <dir>` you configure the tool that will build your project (read that twice). Then with `cmake --build <dir>` you actually do *build* the project, ie. compile and link the sources and create the executable that you can actually run. It's a 2-step process.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much for clarifying this! The last paragraph is especially helpful. Can I ask what the difference is between "cmake --build ." and  "cmake --build <dir>"? Or do they do the same thing? I ran the former.

Comment: Dot represents the current working directory.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing)#Unix_style